# org.onap.logging.filter.base.PayloadLoggingClientFilter does not support jakarta

Tags: spring-boot

I am migrating my application to spring boot 3.1.6 but my onap logging filters does not work, for example org.onap.logging.filter.base.PayloadLoggingClientFilter still uses javax and not jakarta.
Do we have any alternatives which does the same?